# Having an issue with a guessing game logic - java client - server

Tags: java

I have a guessing game.
It has two parts. A server and a Client side.
Both of the classes are included in this post.
The Logic checks for a user input to be in a certain range.
If the check is successfull, user input and a logic's guess is compared.
The Logic must loop itself, letting a user try more 'rounds'.

My only problem is that the code exites the logic loop and doesn't iterate the intended second time and so on.

This is my **Server** code:

```
 public class ServerNum     {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException     {
        adivinarNum juego = new adivinarNum();
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        Socket client = null;
        String resultado;
        boolean correcto = false;
        int intentos;
        
                try     {
                    socket = new ServerSocket(1234);
                }     catch(IOException ioe)     {
                    System.err.println(ioe);
                    return;     }
                    System.out.println("El servidor sigue funcionando...");
                    client = socket.accept();
                    System.out.println("El cliente se ha conectado");
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
        while(!correcto)     {
                intentos = in.readInt();
                resultado = juego.adivinar(intentos);
                correcto = juego.getCorrecto();
                out.writeUTF(resultado);
                out.writeBoolean(correcto);
                out.flush();
            if(correcto == false){
                client = socket.accept();
                intentos = in.readInt();
                resultado = juego.adivinar(intentos);
                correcto = juego.getCorrecto();
                out.writeUTF(resultado);
                out.writeBoolean(correcto);
                out.flush();
              }     else     {
                client.close();
                socket.close();     }     }     }     }
```

and **Client** code:

```
        public class ClientNum     {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException     {
            System.out.println("This is Number Guessing Game. \nChoose any number between 1 to 1000 : ");
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
           int attempt = 0;
           try     {
             attempt = keyboard.nextInt();
             if(attempt < 1 || attempt > 999)     {
               System.out.println("Your number is too large/small, please make a guess between 1 to 1000");
               attempt = keyboard.nextInt();     }     }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)     {
          System.out.println("Just choose numbers! Try again");
          attempt = keyboard.nextInt();     }
        try     {
                    Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");
        
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(server.getOutputStream()));
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
                        
                    out.writeInt(attempt);
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("Our server is still running...");
                    String result = in.readUTF();
                    boolean correct = in.readBoolean();
                    System.out.println(result);
        
                    while (!correct)     {
                            attempt = keyboard.nextInt();
                            out.writeInt(attempt);
                            out.flush();
                            System.out.println("Our server is still running...");
                            result = in.readUTF();
                            System.out.println(result);
                            correct = in.readBoolean();     }
        
                        server.close();
                        System.out.println("Finish. Thank you");
                        System.exit(0);
        
                }     catch(IOException ioe)     {
                    System.err.println(ioe);     }     }     }
```

Where is my error?

Comment: You are calling `socket.accept()` every time a client guessed wrong, i don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.accept` is used to accept a connection to a client.  This means that it is used to start communicating with a client and therefore, only needs to be called once per connection.  Also, your client drops the connection as soon as it gets an answer correct and then reaches the end of its `main()` method, which means that the program ends there.

You should design your program such that a connection is established and then the game code is played inside a `while` loop, often known as the "game-loop" until the user no longer wishes to play.  When the user no longer wishes to play, allow the loop to end, and then let it close its connections to the server, such that the application may shut down gracefully.

It should be noted that the `accept` method has an efficiency overhead associated with it and therefore the program will run more efficiently if you do not have to invoke it as often.